# Transcendence of algebraic numbers with Transcendental power

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, transcendental-numbers

It is known $\log\alpha$ is a transcendental number if $\alpha\neq0,1$ is algebraic. I am wondering if $$\beta^{\log\alpha}\notin\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$$ is also transcendental when $\beta$ is algebraic. Is this question still open or any reference/progress for this question ? Thank you!

Comment: According to Wikipedia - Numbers proven to be Transcendental : $a^b$ where $a$ is algebraic, but not $0$ or $1$, and $b$ is irrational Algebraic.

Comment: Indeed, but in this case the exponent is not algebraic- it is the logarithm of an algebraic number, which is transcendental.

Comment: @lspil you're right! That's why I ask this question.

Comment: @Thomas Is log the natural logarithm ?

Comment: What might help : $a^{\ln(b)}=b^{\ln(a)}$

Comment: @Peter yes! it's the natural logarithm.  Roughly speaking, my question is $$\textrm{(Transcendental Number)^(Transcendental Number)}$$ or $$\textrm{(Algebraic Number)^(Transcendental Number)} = \textrm{"Almost" Transcendental Number.}$$ Is there any reference? Appreciate!